# 4 column layout with custom width 4th column in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a layout with bootstrap 3. It's a 4 column layout where the 4th one takes more width in the layout.

following is a mock-up of the layout.

[image]

How can I achieve this with bootstrap column structure?

Comment: you can use use it by col-md-2.col-md-2,col-md-2,col-md-4 by this you can acheive this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">..</div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">..</div>
 <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2 col-lg-2">..</div>
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-lg-6">..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm quite new to bootstrap! :)

Comment: Its ok.. You are welcome.. If you need any further details about bootstrap grid see this link http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid